# Combining MATLAB and C++ code in Latex

Tags: formatting, listings

I have included MATLAB code in my report with `\begin{lstlisting}` and `\end{lstlisting}` but, in the same report, I need to include C++ code. I want it to recognise the language and highlight with colors and so on. How can I do that?

Update: I can write C++ code now, but I don't know why it doesn't highlight the strings.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
 \definecolor{commentgreen}{rgb}{.133,.545,.133}
 \definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.224, 0.176, 0.255}
\lstdefinestyle{defaultStyle}
{
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
  tabsize=2,
  captionpos=b,
 % frame=lines,
  breaklines=true,
  keepspaces=true
  upquote=true,
}

% define C++ style
\lstdefinestyle{cpp}
{
  style=defaultStyle,
  % language related
  language=C++,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{commentgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  showstringspaces=false,
  %otherkeywords={\#include}, % do not uncomment!
%  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,style=cpp]
// (1) Defining the path and Loading the Classifier (C format)
char      *CascadeFile = "MyCascade/Cascade.xml";
cascade = ( CvHaarClassifierCascade* )cvLoad( CascadeFile);

// (2) Defining the path and Loading the Classifier in (C++ format)
string RootCascade = "MyCascade/";
string Extension = ".xml";
string filename = RootCascade + "Cascade" + Extension;
cascade = ( CvHaarClassifierCascade* )cvLoad( filename.c_str());
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: exactly the same but specify `C++` rather than matlab as the language in the listings setup argument. What did you try?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain it a little more? All I have for Matlab is this:

\usepackage[]{mcode}

Then when I write code inside {lstlistings} it recognises it as MATLAB language. I do not know what to do for C++ code.

Comment: @Zynk Please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)that shows what you have done so far :-) Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `mcode` package defines language settings  for MATLAB at the global scope (with `\lstset`), which is very inconvenient if you also want to typeset listings written in other languages than MATLAB (C++, here) in the same document. The [`matlab-prettifier`](https://github.com/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package obviates this limitation; it's available on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier).

Comment: Have a close look on the options you pass `\lstdefinestyle{}`. All options must be followed by a comma except the last one. You have such an error in the definition of your defaultStyle and you also may want to consider to change the string color from mauve to something less blackish.

Comment: @DohnJoe *[...] except the last one.* Actually, a comma at the end doesn't harm, and is actually desirable, if you later and lines after that.

Comment: Okay, I had not realised that it works but it looks black, I took the mauve RGB values from the Internet thinking it is the colour used in C++. Does any of you know which is the actual colour for strings in C++? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define styles for the listings package

```
% define general style
\lstdefinestyle{defaultStyle}
{
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
  tabsize=2,
  captionpos=b,
  frame=lines,
  breaklines=true,
  keepspaces=true
}
% define C++ style
\lstdefinestyle{cppStyle}
{
  style=defaultStyle,
  % language related
  language=C++,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  showstringspaces=false,
  %otherkeywords={\#include}, % do not uncomment!
  % numbering
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny
}
```

In the latex document, you specify the style with the `style` keyword

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=cppStyle,caption={Code Numbered},label=lst:numbered] 
/* your code here */
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: I am using the same code you provided for me, but in the C++ case, the strings are not highlighted in any color, why can that be?

Comment: Can you post a minimal example?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have been very busy, I posted an example. Thanks